# SSRS Subscription "include link" stopped working correctly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Data-driven subscription

The "Include Link" option is set to "True".

The email the user receives includes the link.  We are finding the link appears to have random 'space' values inserted in odd places, and the user receives an error when clicking the link.  We have another subscription, virtually identical to this one except for one parameter set differently and the link in that email works fine.

> Reporting Services Error
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------   An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'Pro ductGroupCode' that
>   is not defined in this report. (rsUnknownReportParameter)

In this case, The link that is included in the email to the user has a space in one of the parameter names.
(Pro ductGroupCode=2001).  ProductGroupCode is a multi-value parameter.

```
http://<ServerName>/ReportServer?%2FSales%20Activity%2FReturns%20Analysis&HidePeriodOverPeriod=False&HideWeekOverWeek=False&LicensedProductIndicator=False&SubSalesChannelCode=BRK&ReportingRegionName%3Aisnull=True&ProductActiveKey%3Aisnull=True&BusinessLineCode=APP&ReportingCountryName=United%20States&ProductGroupCode=2000&ProductGroupCode=3007&ProductGroupCode=3003&ProductGroupCode=2002&ProductGroupCode=1005&ProductGroupCode=6001&ProductGroupCode=6005&ProductGroupCode=1003&ProductGroupCode=7001&ProductGroupCode=6003&ProductGroupCode=1004&ProductGroupCode=3001&ProductGroupCode=3002&ProductGroupCode=3006&ProductGroupCode=3005&ProductGroupCode=6006&ProductGroupCode=2003&ProductGroupCode=6004&ProductGroupCode=6002&ProductGroupCode=1001&ProductGroupCode=3004&Pro ductGroupCode=2001&ProductGroupCode=2005&ProductGroupCode=Unk&ProductGroupCode=1002&ProductGroupCode=&IsSample=N&BusinessAreaCode=BRO&ReportingDivisionName=North%20America&Currency=USD&CustomerTypeCode=0&RankBy=ReturnQty&report_TopN=20&HideYearOverYear=True&RankType=ItemName&rs%3AParameterLanguage=en-US
```

EDIT:
Here is another example.  It is happening on a different parameter but it's the same issue.  There is no space:
[image: Clearly the ReportingDivisionName has no space in the link]

However if I right-click the hyperlink, "copy hyperlink", and paste to notepad, I get this.  The underlying hyperlink has a space in it.

[image: Where did the space come from?]

Here is the text.

http://ebiprd-atl01/ReportServer?%2FSales%20Activity%2FReturns%20Analysis&HidePeriodOverPeriod=False&HideWeekOverWeek=False&LicensedProductIndicator=False&SubSalesChannelCode=BRK&ReportingRegionName%3Aisnull=True&ProductActiveKey%3Aisnull=True&BusinessLineCode=APP&ReportingCountryName=United%20States&ProductGroupCode=2000&ProductGroupCode=3007&ProductGroupCode=3003&ProductGroupCode=2002&ProductGroupCode=1005&ProductGroupCode=6001&ProductGroupCode=6005&ProductGroupCode=1003&ProductGroupCode=7001&ProductGroupCode=6003&ProductGroupCode=1004&ProductGroupCode=3001&ProductGroupCode=3002&ProductGroupCode=3006&ProductGroupCode=3005&ProductGroupCode=6006&ProductGroupCode=2003&ProductGroupCode=6004&ProductGroupCode=6002&ProductGroupCode=1001&ProductGroupCode=3004&ProductGroupCode=2001&ProductGroupCode=2005&ProductGroupCode=Unk&ProductGroupCode=1002&ProductGroupCode=&IsSample=N&BusinessAreaCode=BRO&ReportingDivisio nName=North%20America&Currency=USD&CustomerTypeCode=0&RankBy=ReturnQty&report_TopN=20&HideYearOverYear=True&RankType=ItemName&rs%3AParameterLanguage=en-US

Comment: You have no control over the built-in "Include Link" option. You could build the URL in your data-driven subscription query and then use that in the Comment field. This will go in the body of the email.

Comment: @Mike I'm sorry my question wasn't more obvious.  Why is it putting a %20 inside one of the parameter names?

Comment: @StevenWhite - I tried that also and we had the same problem.

Comment: @Bostaevski the space appears at column 768 in the URL, can you try some different queries and see if the space appears in the same place?

Comment: @Mike - I edited the question above with some screenshots.  In that example, it occurs around 917.

Answer (score 0):

%20 isn't random - it is a a space.

Your link has been encoded to ensure it will work in a universal way.

[URL encoding explained.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

If you don't want to see %20 then remove the spaces from your report name.

You have a %2F at the beginning of your parameter list - this looks odd.

If the parameter is still invalid check you have the latest version deployed to your report server - **ServerName** (I assume) has been replace by you?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am aware that %20 is a space.  My point is that it has been "randomly" inserted into the URL for no reason.  

In this case, ProductGroupCode is a multivalue parameter so it appears many times.

What I expect to see in the URL string is something like this
...&ProductGroupCode=3004&ProductGroupCode=2001...
However, there is a %20 inserted in one of them
...&ProductGroupCode=3004&Pro%20ductGroupCode=2001&...

Why?

Comment: To complicate this, the %20 inside the ProductGroupCode param name only happens for the user.  When *I* try to copy the hyperlink from my email and paste in notepad, I instead see a %20 inserted in a different parameter.

In my case it is a param called ReportingDivisionName, where the encoded URL has inexplicably put a %20 right in the middle of the parameter name:  ReportingDivisio%20nName=North%20America

Comment: on second thought I think it's not putting a %20 in the link.  It is putting a literal space.  However when you try opening that in IE, IE will replace the space with a %20.  Either way the outcome is the same.